# Can't access Magento Admin on Multiple Computers (IPv6 Issue)

Tags: magento2

This is a complicated issue for me so I will do my best to explain the steps I have taken to try to figure out what is going on. The issue seems to be coming from ipv6 on my server if I had to give my best guess because the issue only seems to happen when I login from a newer computer. This issue only just happened by the way. I was able to login before with the same computer and I have made no changes on my end.

Here is what I see when I try to login from a newer computer that uses ipv6

[image]

When I do a ping for my website from this same computer, this is what I get

[image]

When I check the ipv6 on my server, this is what I get

[image]

So is this a magento login issue that someone has come across or is this a server issue that I'm not aware of? Does anyone know what to do to fix this?

UPDATE: I have confirmed that any computer that uses ipv6 can't access my magento admin section but any computer that uses ipv4 can access without any issues and I need to figure out how to fix this issue instead of asking all my customers and employees to disable their ipv6

UPDATE 2: This is what I saw after I ran the command from below

```
[root@www ~]# netstat -anlp | grep 80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1936/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1101/varnishd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59576         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59652         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59682         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:60414         127.0.0.1:80            ESTABLISHED 1946/nginx: worker
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59662         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:58310         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59606         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 74.208.125.26:443       162.158.2.176:14180     ESTABLISHED 1949/nginx: worker
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          127.0.0.1:52140         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59644         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59672         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:58900         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59646         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59580         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59674         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59302         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59620         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59618         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59622         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59634         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:58060         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59638         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59572         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:58542         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:58124         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59582         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:60038         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59890         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59572         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59676         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59684         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:58436         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:60124         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59618         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59642         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:58746         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:47280         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 23121/php-fpm: pool
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59574         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59614         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          127.0.0.1:53940         ESTABLISHED 1949/nginx: worker
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59664         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59654         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54190         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 5280/php
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59652         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59666         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59574         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59698         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53940         127.0.0.1:8080          ESTABLISHED 1101/varnishd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59636         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59560         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59698         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:60060         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54262         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED 5280/php
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59612         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59584         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:60310         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59690         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59576         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59660         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59678         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59270         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59686         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59672         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59612         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59558         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:60414         ESTABLISHED 1101/varnishd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59674         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          127.0.0.1:54032         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59686         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:58002         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59644         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59430         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59640         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:57348         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59610         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59648         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59556         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59688         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59656         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59892         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59012         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:58216         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59670         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59684         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59640         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:57934         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:57638         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59690         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59620         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          127.0.0.1:55530         ESTABLISHED 1943/nginx: worker
tcp        0      0 74.208.125.26:443       162.158.79.87:33380     ESTABLISHED 1956/nginx: worker
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59014         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59692         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:55530         127.0.0.1:8080          ESTABLISHED 1101/varnishd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59712         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59608         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59580         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:58030         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59682         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59582         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:60342         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59656         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59694         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 74.208.125.26:443       172.68.65.106:22805     ESTABLISHED 1950/nginx: worker
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59658         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59694         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 74.208.125.26:443       172.68.65.46:18050      ESTABLISHED 1941/nginx: worker
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59680         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59696         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:57986         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          127.0.0.1:50564         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59650         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59664         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59616         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59578         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:47280         ESTABLISHED 1585/redis-server 1
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59678         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59696         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59714         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 74.208.125.26:443       162.158.78.194:22803    ESTABLISHED 1956/nginx: worker
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59534         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59904         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59646         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:60342         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:58004         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1101/varnishd
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:33284 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53600 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54466 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54516 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53648 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:34802 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53670 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54498 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53650 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:34480 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:33442 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52930 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:51852 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53234 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:33580 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53298 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54646 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54084 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:34580 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:33440 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52748 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 74.208.125.26:2408      108.162.214.232:12280   ESTABLISHED 1657/rg-listener
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54078 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54492 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:60980 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54312 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54082 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:33802 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54308 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52516 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:33126 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53486 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:33586 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53642 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52922 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53112 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53456 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52538 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53606 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:42280 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 74.208.125.26:2408      162.158.68.88:26801     ESTABLISHED 1657/rg-listener
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53286 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:34180 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53482 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:33632 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52668 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:33380 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53676 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:32800 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52736 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53786 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:34780 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53778 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53854 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54160 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54464 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54528 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53284 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53232 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53644 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53824 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53304 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:32980 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52556 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53860 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:33800 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52492 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53864 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:34804 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54162 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53088 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53656 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54652 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53410 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52018 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54460 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:32860 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53652 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:33144 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:32914 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52676 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 74.208.125.26:2408      162.158.57.82:35880     ESTABLISHED 1657/rg-listener
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53230 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:60804 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52352 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:42804 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53296 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53414 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53784 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:32802 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53042 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52858 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:33100 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53852 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:33060 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53046 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:33624 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:42780 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52674 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:33980 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54132 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54510 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52876 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53466 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52746 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52740 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54086 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54138 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:33808 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53674 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 74.208.125.26:2408      172.68.208.226:28040    ESTABLISHED 1657/rg-listener
tcp6       0      0 74.208.125.26:2408      162.158.70.180:39484    ESTABLISHED 1657/rg-listener
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53964 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52326 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54270 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:32900 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:34800 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53412 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52554 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54530 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54276 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54128 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:33634 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:34380 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53116 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53966 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:33628 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54080 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 74.208.125.26:2408      108.162.220.202:58030   ESTABLISHED 1657/rg-listener
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52734 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:60480 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52860 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:51832 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52918 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:32912 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54654 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53408 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52898 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52750 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52190 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:33150 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54500 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53618 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:54532 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52908 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:33804 2400:cb00:2048:1::6:443 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53830 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:52548 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 2607:f1c0:860:1e0:53098 2400:cb00:2048:1::68:80 TIME_WAIT   -                               1014/ntpd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     863118   13680/php-fpm: pool
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6249574  5280/php
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6242970  5280/php
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3403380  23080/php-fpm: pool
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     22280    1936/nginx: master
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6269066  5280/php
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6318024  23121/php-fpm: pool
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6247192  5280/php
```

Comment: I would say ths is more a webserver problem than a Magento problem. It would be good to let us know what OS and web server software you are using. Is Magento the only website running on your server?

Comment: @paj yes magento is the only website running on my server and I'm using centos 7 and nginx + varnish

Comment: Is it just the backend (admin) that is inaccessible via IPv6 clients or the frontend too?

Comment: @paj  It is just the backend that isn't working for ipv6 clients

Answer (score 0):

Ensure NGINX is listening on port 80/443 for IPv4 and IPv6

Run `netstat -anlp | grep 80`

```
tcp        0      0 x.x.227.20:80        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23047/httpd         
tcp6       0      0 2400:x:0:d0::1f33:80 :::*                    LISTEN      23047/httpd
```

If you do not see a tcp6 entry check your NGINX .conf to make sure it is enabled for IPv6.

```
listen       [::]:80 default_server;
```

Comment: I updated my post to show what I see when I ran that command but I'm getting a bunch of responses and what am I supposed to do with the listen command?

Comment: It looks like you are running Varnish in front of Nginx so that would be the next place to check.

Comment: What command do I run to check and what am I checking for?

Comment: My bounty expired even though I still don't have an answer yet so can you please help me? I think the bounty went to you by default even though I don't have a resolution for this issue

Comment: the bounty is only awarded to an accepted answer.

Comment: Well my bounty hasn't appeared back into my account yet and I don't have enough points to do another bounty

Comment: I am happy to try and help you further but without access to your server this is difficult to troubleshoot, as you say it is only the magento backend that is inaccessible it must be an nginx or varnish configuration problem.

Comment: I will give you access to my server if I have to. I'm completely flustered and out of ideas at this point and my server knowledge is pretty basic